# Removed Switch statement to resolve error and error persists.

Tags: java, compiler-errors, switch-statement

Here is my issue. I removed the switch statement from this method as I had to alter it to accommodate multiple variables whereas the switch statement only allows char constant. Could not use Strings for variables without java version 7. So what I have done is changed to usual if/else statements to go through. But when trying to run the program I am still getting an error on the switch statement as follows:

Any ideas? If would like me to include code from tester I can just ask.

> java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:      Cannot switch on a
>   value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int
>   values or enum variables are permitted
>
> at Project2.PostfixEvaluator.calculate(PostfixEvaluator.java:124)   at
>   Project2.PostfixEvaluator.eval(PostfixEvaluator.java:71)  at
>   Project2.ExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(ExpressionEvaluator.java:29)    at
>   Project2.ExpressionEvaluatorTester.main(ExpressionEvaluatorTester.java:32)

```
public Token calculate(Token opr, Token opd1, Token opd2)
    {
        // Get the first String from opr, it is the operator: +, -, ...
        String oper = opr.getBody();

        System.out.println(opr);

        //Get the two operands by converting from String to int
        int op1 = Integer.parseInt(opd1.getBody());
        int op2 = Integer.parseInt(opd2.getBody());

        //Default return value, in case an error occurs
        int res = 0;

        /**
         * Alterations begin here
         * Performs operation and sets value for res
         */

           if(oper.equals("+")) 
           {
               res = op1+op2;
           }
           else if(oper.equals("-"))
           {
               res = op1-op2;  
           }
           else if(oper.equals("*")){
               res = op1*op2;
           }
           else if(oper.equals("/") && op2 != 0){
               res = op1/op2;
           }
           else if(oper.equals("/") && op2 == 0){
               System.out.println("Division by zero error in"+
                 " PostfixEvaluator.calculate().");
           }
           else if(oper.equals("%") && op2 != 0){
                res = op1%op2;
           }
           else if(oper.equals("%") && op2 == 0){
                System.out.println("Division by zero error in"+
                 " PostfixEvaluator.calculate().");
           }
           else if(oper.equals("<") && (op1 < op2)){
                res = 1;
           }
           else if(oper.equals("<") && (op1 >= op2)){
                res = 0;
           }
           else if(oper.equals("<=") && (op1 <= op2)){
                res = 1;
           }
           else if(oper.equals("<=") && (op1 > op2)){
                res = 0;
           }
           else if(oper.equals(">") && (op1 > op2)){
                res = 1;
           }
           else if(oper.equals(">") && (op1 <= op2)){
                res = 0;
           }
           else if(oper.equals(">=") && (op1 >= op2)){
                res = 1;
           }
           else if(oper.equals(">=") && (op1 < op2)){
                res = 0;
           }
           else if(oper.equals("==") && (op1 == op2)){
                res = 1;
           }
           else if(oper.equals("==") && (op1 != op2)){
                res = 0;
           }
           else if(oper.equals("!=") && (op1 != op2)){
                res = 1;
           }
           else if(oper.equals("!=") && (op1 == op2)){
                res = 0;
           }
           else if(oper.equals("||") && true){
                res = 1;
           }
           else if(oper.equals("&&")&& true){
                res = 1;
           }
           else
               res = 0;





        //Convert res into a Token and return it.
        return new Token(""+res);

}
```

Comment: Errors are always persist but you cannot see em.

Answer (score 6):

Since this is not a compiler error, but a runtime error, it means that you changed the source code, but failed to recompile it, or at least failed to run the recompiled code.

The error definitely concerns an issue with a `switch` statement in the source code, but you have deleted that from your source code file. It must be therefore that you are loading a stale version of .class file. Check whether the *Build Automatically* option is activated and/or do a full project clean + rebuild.

Comment: I have ran the code several times. I am using Eclipse so it compiles whenever saved and I save constantly. I have also went through the debugger several times with no resolution.

Comment: It's kind of a compiler error and a runtime error, but kind of neither.  When Eclipse can't compile some code but you still choose to run it, it compiles the bytecode which will throw this error instead.

Comment: Okay what do you suggest I do to resolve? Remove and remake class?

Comment: Since the posted error is definitely related to a switch statement you have removed from the source code, the only explanation is that you are loading stale .class files at runtime. Is "Build Automatically" perhaps disabled?

Comment: I will check that. What menu is that option in? Forgive me as I have only been using Eclipse for a couple months now and am still learning the basics.

Comment: Try pressing ctrl-3 and then typing "build automatically". Otherwise it is under the *Project* menu.

Comment: Build automatically was not disabled. I really appreciate the recommendation though. Any other ideas?

Comment: Clean and rebuild is the next logical step, then checking your build path and compiled class output folder (these are under Project properties, Java build path).

Comment: Thank you. Tried that with no resolution as I am not getting a cannot find main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Project/ExpressionEvaluatorTester
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Project.ExpressionEvaluatorTester
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"

Comment: I am concerned that it is a issue with Eclipse itself. Should I try and uninstall and reinstall? I have never had this issue before with Eclipse

Comment: Are you trying to run your program as a Java Applet instead of Java Application?

Comment: I am not sure is there a way to change that option?

Answer (score 0):

Perform a clean build and then run your program:

**Clean:** `Menu --> Project --> clean`

**Build:** `Menu --> Project --> Build Automatically`

or          `Menu --> Project -->Build All which is same as: ctrl+B`

**Run:** `Right Click(Your PostfixEvaluator.java) -> Run As -> Java Application`